# Hibernate long conversation isolation level

Tags: hibernate

I'm learning the way of Hibernate now and a bit stuck with concurrency over long conversation session.

I have a web application with long conversation with two request-response cycle. The first lists some rows in a db table, and a form where the user can submit a new row. The second lists all the rows with the newly added row.

Is there a way to define or implement a way for the whole long conversation session to behave like a serializable transaction?

User story:

1. We have 2 users inspecting the same first page with the listed table rows.
2. The first user puts in some data into the form and submits, and sees the the new list with the added row.
3. The second user tries to submit a new row, but gets some kind of isolation exception for trying to insert to a data set which number has changed.

I can think of some workaround with adding the data set to the httpsession and compare it on the other side, but i hope there is a better way.

Comment: Please provide your codes as well

Comment: It's not really a "look at my code where is the problem" kind of question. I have multiple codes in wicket-spring-hibernate for different scenarios, like optimistic concurrency control for update with versioning which works, and which is an implementation for Repeatable read on long converstion. I'm looking for a way to do the same with Serializable, so no rows can be added or deleted concurrently.

Comment: Or some guidance where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not like a SERIALIZABLE transaction, but you can ensure data integrity using [optimistic locking](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/).

Optimistic locking along with a stateful storage (extended persistence context or detached entities) can give you [application-level repeatable reads](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-application-level-repeatable-reads/), so you can guarantee an entity state integrity over multiple user requests.

The pessimistic locking is not an option for you and the only workaround is to use logical locking strategies, that's why optimistic locking is the best option over multiple requests.